# Does an extension exist for Visual Studio which allows quick switching between different development roles?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm generally a C++ guy, but I've got to switch to C# some of the time in order to build things for the "Windows Phone" platform. Or when I have to go to work. Whatever. Point is, I work very differently when I'm in C++ than when I'm in C#.

I'd like to have a quick and fast way of switching between these two. I know there's a "save all settings" and "restore all settings" bit, but it's awfully slow to fire up the IDE using the wrong settings, reload the other settings, close the IDE back down again, and then restart it. Ideally, I'd like to key these settings based off what kind of project I have open. E.g. if a C++ project exists in the solution, use C++ settings, otherwise use C#/XAML settings.

Does such an extension exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly an extension, but take a look at this blog post by Sara Ford: [Did you know… You can create toolbar buttons to quickly toggle your favorite VS Settings?](http://saraford.net/2008/12/05/did-you-know-you-can-create-toolbar-buttons-to-quickly-toggle-your-favorite-vs-settings-372/)